# Prevent pagebreak in kableExtra landscape table

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

How can a landscape table be plotted in R Markdown (PDF output) without causing a page break to be inserted?

There is the function `landscape` from the **kableExtra** package, but this forces a page break to be inserted.

**Example:**

The normal behaviour for tables in R Markdown is that the will float to minimise the breaking up of text.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

Some Text

```{r, echo=F, warning=F}
library(kableExtra)
knitr::kable(mtcars, format = "latex", caption = "A table")
```

More Text
````

[image]

**Landscape**:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

Some Text

```{r, echo=F, warning=F}
library(kableExtra)
knitr::kable(mtcars, format = "latex", booktabs = T, caption = "A table") %>%
  landscape()
```

More Text
````

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the LaTeX package realboxes to do what you want

````
---
title: "Mixing portrait and landscape"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
---

Some text

\Rotatebox{90}{
```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

knitr::kable(mtcars, "latex", booktabs = TRUE)
```
}
More text
````

This produces a single page pdf with the table presented in landscape. The problem with this approach is that it does not seem to work with a caption.

[image]

**Edit** You can use the `caption` latex package to add the caption

````
---
title: "Mixing portrait and landscape"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[graphicx]{realboxes}
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage{caption}
---

Some text


\begingroup 
\captionsetup{type=table}
\caption{A table}
\Rotatebox{90}{

```{r, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE}

knitr::kable(mtcars, "latex", booktabs = TRUE)
```

}
\endgroup

More text
````

This produces the table in landscape with caption

[image]